# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined - Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently developping a web app using Google Maps Javascript API. Everything worked just fine until a few hours ago, when I got these errors :

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '15' of undefined`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined`
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Notre super indicateur</h1>
        <div id="map" style="width:1000px; height:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my script.js file :

```
function initMap() {

    var tab = arrayData;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 48.856583, lng: 2.337341},
        zoom: 12
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('some GeoJSON file');

    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {

        var color;
        var nb = feature.getProperty("c_qu");

        if (tab[nb-1].index < 0.3) {
            color = "red";
        }
        else if (tab[nb-1].index < 0.6) {
            color = "orange";
        }
        else {
            color = "green";
        }

        return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
            fillColor: color,
            strokeColor: "grey",
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
    });

}
```

*Note : arrayData is defined in my main.js file*

This is really weird : the error is said to be in my script.js file, however when I update it the error stays at the same line. Weirder is the fact that once in 15 or 20 times, it perfectly works (and my code is also on GitHub Pages and it works fine).

Could someone help me with this? Thank you very much !
Tom.

Comment: Property '15' and '9' are indices of array. Your array 'arrayData' is not generating those many elements then...check it's size on every run, along with nb-1.

Comment: @dev8080 It does not change anything: sometimes it works (arrayData.length = 80), and sometimes it says arrayData is undefined (and I did not change anything)

Comment: That arrayData is undefined (even if sometimes) explains everything. Your errors are caused by that. Try fighting the condition by placing all your code inside if(arrayData) or handling if(!arrayData)

Comment: @dev8080 Yes I perfectly understand, I just wanted to know where the problem come from... It was working yesterday and it is working from times to times...

Comment: @dev8080 Plus, when adding a if(arrayData) condition, my page just doesn't load 80% of the time...